# Jupyter Notebook Plotly Charts Not Rendering in PDF via Latex

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have created a report in Jupyter notebook using plotly to graph charts and have also installed the necessary packages to create a PDF from my notebook. When converting to PDF Everything displays with the exception of the plotly charts. My code looks similar to the one in the documentation.

```
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.show()
```

I have tried adding fig.show(render='pdf') and thats does not work the notebook converts to pdf but still no chart. I do not see much in the documentation related to this. Any help would be greatly apprciated.

Comment: You'd need to render the plot as an image or PDF and then incorporate it. See [here](https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/#interactive-vs-static-export).

Comment: Thank you I am working on that now. Installing orca hopefully I can get everything to render by eod.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with WSL not supporting orca which is a known issue.